# Interactive task scheduler recommendations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake

Hey folks, I am looking for something to manage and schedule the execution of rake tasks, like database backups or running reports; something that has a nice web interface so I don't have to use cron. I'm looking at hudson, but it seems this is more geared toward CI builds. Rather than roll my own, does anyone have any recommendations on things to try?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I haven't noticed your post earlier. Try http://scheduler.codeeffects.com, http://www.webbasedcron.com or http://www.webcron.org